# SAS expander card, not detecting DAS, is this supposed to work?

Tags: hp-smart-array, sas, direct-attached-storage, hp-modular-smart-array

I have a similar sas expander HSTNM-B017 and when I connect an external DAS unit to it (HP StorageWorkd MSA50) nothing shows up in device manager or disk manager, as if its not connected.

do you have to take the connection from the DAS -> SAS Expander -> SAS raid card? for the drives to show up?

pics https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BD6410D8116F20FA!525446&authkey=!ANkGvQftmnB5lwE&ithint=folder%2c

Answer (score 1):

[In this photo](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ANkGvQftmnB5lwE&cid=BD6410D8116F20FA&id=BD6410D8116F20FA%21525443&parId=BD6410D8116F20FA%21525446&o=OneUp), you're missing something very critical.

The SAS expander needs to be connected to the LSI/Avago RAID controller in your system. You need two more SAS SFF-8087 cables to connect the ports that say, "TO CONTROLLER".

Answer (score -3):

You need to connect ports 8c/9c to the onboard controller ports 1/2